# Sumatoria de números

Tags: c#, funciones, sumatoria

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa con funciones en C# que me calcule la sumatoria desde el número 1 hasta n.

Este es el ejercicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que sucede es que al correr el programa, en vez de que me arroje un resultado, muestra unas siglas que dicen NaN, entonces qué es lo que puede estar mal, ya intenté varias soluciones y me sigue arrojando lo mismo. Este es el código:

```
/*Sumatoria*/
using System;

int n;
int x;
int i;

Console.WriteLine(" Da el valor de n ");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Da el valor de x");
x= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Da el valor de i");
i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("La sumatoria es de " + Sumatoria(n, x, i));

static double Sumatoria(int n, int x, int i)
{

    double suma = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        suma = (suma + Potencia(x, i))/i;

    }

    Console.WriteLine(suma);

    return suma;
}    

static int Potencia(int x, int i)
{
    x = i;
    int potencia = 1;

    for(int j = 0; j <= x; j++)
    {
        potencia = potencia * x;
    }

    return potencia;
}
```

Comment: Este entrenamiento te va a caer muy bien: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqQuCJT2gG8&t=1561s Te ayudará a entender mejor la respuesta de @Yussef

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero es que tienes un error en tu función, i no puede comenzar en cero, porque en la función divides por cero.

La función sumatoria;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De forma genérica, debería verse así:

```
public static decimal Sumatatoria(int i, int n)
{
    decimal result = 0;
    for (int j=i ; j<=n; j++)
    {
        result += f(j);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Donde f(j) es:

```
public static decimal ElevayDivide(int x, int i)
        => Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(x, i) / i);
```

Ahora el trabajo es juntar ambas funciones, para esto ocuparé Expressions, quedando la función Sumatoria de esta manera:

```
public static decimal Sumatatoria(int i, int n, Expression<Func<int , decimal>> funcion)
{
    decimal result = 0;
    var f = funcion.Compile();
    for (int j=i ; j<=n; j++)
    {
        result += f.Invoke(j);
    }
    return result;
}
```

De esta manera nuestra función sumatoria recibe como argumentos i y n (valores tipicos de la sumatoria) y además una Expressión que representa la función a sumar. Esta Expression puede ser lo que queramos, pero en particular será la función ElevayDivide

Como usarla??

```
int i = 1;
int n = 100;
int x = 23; //constante
var resultado1 = Sumatatoria(i, n, a => ElevayDivide(x,a));
var resultado2 = Sumatatoria(i, n, a => a); //sumatoria del 1 al 100
var resultado3 = Sumatatoria(i, n, a => a*a); //sumatoria del 1 al 100 de los número al cuadrado
```

Comment: Como apunte Double.Nan se utiliza para representar no numérico como por ejemplo divir por zero.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución alternativa, haciendo uso de **Linq**, de esta forma tu código quedará más compacto:

```
int x = 3;
var sumatoria = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Sum((n) => Math.Pow(x, n) / n);

Console.WriteLine(sumatoria);
```

Aquí se usa el **operador Range** el cual para este ejemplo que te pongo genera una lista de **3** elementos consecutivos del **1** al **3**, posteriormente se aplica el **operador Sum** el cual será el encargado de hacer el cálculo correspondiente, devolviendo la sumatoria correspondiente.

Finalmente se imprime el resultado obtenido.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Nota**: Esta es una solución alternativa a cualquier cosa que te hayan pedido en la escuela, para que veas que hay otras vías de solución a este problema y conozcas **Linq** en caso de que no sepas que es.